# Match background-image scale-level in header over background-size:cover

Tags: html, css

I have a two block elements, the first one (`<section>`) being the size of the browser window and rendering a dynamically sized background image (using `background-size: cover;`). The other one a fixed `<header>` with constant height of 62px and a bigger `z-index`.

HTML body:

```
<header></header>
<section></section>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    height: 62px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(image.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
 }
section {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(image.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I want the background image of the `<header>` to have a "scale-factor" equal to that of the `<section>`, but only showing the constant height. That means it should show exactly the first 62 pixel rows that the `<section>` element is rendering, and therefore be invisible to the user (when he is at vertical position 0/hasn't scrolled yet).

Link to a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f1nhum9u/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `fixed` behavior for the bg header. With background-attachment:

> This keyword means that the background is fixed with regard to the viewport. Even if an element has a scrolling mechanism, a ‘fixed’ background doesn't move with the element.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 62px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/696289main_O_Star_Binary.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
  background-size: cover;
  /*ADD THIS*/
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
section {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/696289main_O_Star_Binary.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<section></section>
<br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but the OP's code does this already (see OP's fiddle, though set height of header to 62px, not 262px) ... without `background-attachment: fixed;` ... and since the header has `position: fixed`, the `background-attachment: fixed;` has no effect

Comment: @LGSon make the screen result smaller on OP's fiddle and after on this snippet

Comment: Yepp ... I didn't sized OP's fiddle that much initially :) ... +1

Comment: This actually works (I am still wondering how exactly). So thanks for that! But I am running into problems somewhere else. I have also pages that uses this style but with a `<section>` height of a constant 300px (instead of 100%). I'd need to assign `background-attachment:fixed;` to that as well, or else the images don't match. But that changes the design somewhat. :/

Comment: Well mate will need to see on action that issue too to help U ... it's too much here maybe @snøreven